# difference between methods to scale a bitmap

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, scale

There are at least two methods to scale a bitmap in Android,
One is to use "inScaled, inDensity, inTargetDensity" in "BitmapFactory.Options" when decode a bitmap source.
The other is to use a "Matrix" in "Bitmap.createBitmap".

What I am curious is what the difference between these two method is?
What about the quality of produced bitmap? And what about the memory usage?
etc...

Answer (score 1):

Using `BitmapFactory` with the proper inScale options will allow you to be more memory efficient than using either `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` or `Bitmap.createBitmap()` with a matrix scale.  However, it is more complicated.

Check out [How do I scale a streaming bitmap in-place without reading the whole image first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051025/how-do-i-scale-a-streaming-bitmap-in-place-without-reading-the-whole-image-first/7051089#7051089) for details.

Answer (score 1):

One difference that I found was that using BitmapFactory`s options.inSampleSize to scale bitmaps is not as granular, because  the scale will be 1/inSampleSize, and because inSampleSize must be an integral number, you wind up with scaling like 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc, but nothing more granular than that.

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`, though more memory intensive, allows more granular scaling, up to 1dp resolution.

Comment: You forgot the inScaled + inDensity + inTargetDensity method which does allow granular scaling. You just have to know the scaling magnitudes and work with inSampleSize.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "big" difference. Although, one benefit with using the `BitmapFactory.Options` is that you can check for the width / height of your `Bitmap` without allocating memory for the actual `Bitmap`'s pixels.

Also, you can easily see which [options `BitmapFactory.Options`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) has and compare that with `Bitmap.createBitmap()`. In general, `BitmapFactory.Options` is like a "tool" API for making decoding and sampling `Bitmap`s easier.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Bitmap.createBitmap ()` becomes faster than using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap ()`.

Using `Bitmap.createBitmap ()` we have already passed the Bitmap creation settings, while with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap ()` height and width are calculated dynamically.

See the example:

```kotlin
/**
 * Return a [Bitmap] representation of this [Drawable].
 *
 * If this instance is a [BitmapDrawable] and the [width], [height], and [config] match, the
 * underlying [Bitmap] instance will be returned directly. If any of those three properties differ
 * then a new [Bitmap] is created. For all other [Drawable] types, a new [Bitmap] is created.
 *
 * @param width Width of the desired bitmap. Defaults to [Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth].
 * @param height Height of the desired bitmap. Defaults to [Drawable.getIntrinsicHeight].
 * @param config Bitmap config of the desired bitmap. Null attempts to use the native config, if
 * any. Defaults to [Config.ARGB_8888] otherwise.
 */
fun Drawable.toBitmap(
    @Px width: Int = intrinsicWidth,
    @Px height: Int = intrinsicHeight,
    config: Config? = null
): Bitmap {
    if (this is BitmapDrawable) {
        if (config == null || bitmap.config == config) {
            // Fast-path to return original. Bitmap.createScaledBitmap will do this check, but it
            // involves allocation and two jumps into native code so we perform the check ourselves.
            if (width == intrinsicWidth && height == intrinsicHeight) {
                return bitmap
            }
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true)
        }
    }

    val (oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) = bounds

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config ?: Config.ARGB_8888)
    setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    draw(Canvas(bitmap))

    setBounds(oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom)
    return bitmap
}
```

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-room-release/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/Drawable.kt#42)